# how to use jar files

Tags: java, swing, jar

I have create an jar file containing external jar files using command prompt. But after creating that jar file I can't access the jar files inside the main jar files. I don't know whether the folder structure has been changed or any other problem.

Command used in command prompt:

```
C:\diretory>jar cf mycollection.jar *
```

'*' - for including all the jar files in folder.

I am just trying to make a single jar file of all the external files I need in my project. It was successfully build but while using it given ClassNotFoundException.
I giving you now full scenario of my problem. Actually I am trying to add all external look and feel jar into single jar file so I don't need to put each and every jar individually. So I created a jar file consisting all the external look and feel jar files. And now while using it like import statement it show no such class is there in my jar file.

Comment: Are you embedding (including) other Jar files into a single Jar file?

Comment: Post 1) The actual error or exception output. 2) The command used to run the Jars. 3) The manifest of the main Jar. 4) A `jar -tvf the.jar` for each class in the class-path/manifest.  --  Without that type of information, all we can do is guess.

Comment: JAR are just ZIP files. Change extension and open with your ZIP utility like 7zip.

Comment: Nested JARs are not part of JavaSE (see the note [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html)), but there are ways around this (some [examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873265/delivering-a-single-jar-with-a-maven-project)).

Comment: ya mad programmer I'm doing the same...

Comment: I cannot for the life of me figure why 2 people thought this was 'well researched and clear'.  -1 for balance.

Answer (score 2):

Java does not supported embedded Jars.  I know, pain.

You could try using something like [One-Jar](http://one-jar.sourceforge.net/) which allows you to embedded multiple Jars into a single "master" Jar, but I had problems with custom classloading, but you might have better luck...

Comment: Mad programmer it just creates an executable jar file but what about calling the classes from jar file itself... I mean import de.javasoft... etc It doesn't allow me to call the classes inside the jar file. Thanks for the answer but doesn't works for me

Comment: You can't then link the resulting Jar for use in your other projects.  OneJar is designed as a tool by which you can package a releasable application.  Then the answer to your question is "no - it' can't be done"

Answer (score 0):

As I'm working with Maven projects I'm using Maven's goal assembly:assembly in order to pack all the files into one (build with dependencies).

Also NetBeans offer "build with dependencies" option might want to check that out as well...